# Matlab Knnimpute Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-analysis

I wanted to run knnimpute function available in Matlab.My dataset contains numerical values along with unicodes. On executing knnimpute i get this strange error

```
ans = knnimpute(raw',1)
Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in knnimpute (line 136)
nanVals = isnan(data);
```

Several rows in my dataset have NAN's in them. All the rows have the following data types

```
Columns 1 through 7

{[25]}    {' Private'}    {[1484705]}    {' Some-college'}    {[10]}    {' Divorced'}    {' Exec-managerial'}
```

Columns 8 through 15

```
{' Unmarried'}    {' White'}    {' Female'}    {[0]}    {[0]}    {[25]}    {' United-States'}
```

This dataset is the [adult dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data) available at UCI Machine learning repository.
So should i preprocess the dataset to one hot encoding or any other technique if so can the technique be described along with the code.

Comment: I am not familiar with the function myself, however from the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/knnimpute.html) it does appear that the input should be a numerical matrix, and not a cell array. Can you perhaps give more information as to what you are trying to achieve? Also you really should not be using `ans` as a variable name as its an internal keyword.

Comment: I am trying to impute values from a dataset that has several missing values along the different columns. My university professor wanted me to use knnimpute for this dataset. After imputing the datset we then compare the dataset with the original dataset.

Comment: I only see missing values in column 12 and 13. What is the criteria for the replacement? Do you perhaps want to extract all numerical values from the cell array, find the missing values, and use the function with only numerical values?

Comment: Those are not the missing values, The missing fields have a NAN in them.For Example                        
ans =

  1×15 cell array

  Columns 1 through 7

    {[NaN]}    {' Private'}    {[13769]}    {' Some-college'}    {[10]}    {' Married-civ-sp…'}    {' Machine-op-ins…'}

  Columns 8 through 15

    {' Husband'}    {' Amer-Indian-Es…'}    {' Male'}    {[0]}    {[0]}    {[30]}    {' United-States'}    {' <=50K'}